# Remembering logging in in Android

Tags: android, facebook, email, authentication

I am trying to build a logging in system (stored in online database) for Android by email and facebook. Right now I coded the logging in for Android by email, but I am wondering how I should best code the part to remember if you are logged in or not the next time you open the app.

Is the best way to do this to simply keep track of this in a shared preferences file with a boolean? And should I store this just by username and then just get all the scored points of this user from the online database? Is it necessary to encrypt this data to my shared pref?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes,shared preference is preferred way to do this.And why only store username,i mean store all the data in shared preference  and then fetch it from there.there's no point in fetching it again and again everytime from server unless it is updatable.

Comment: You should now that the game will need internet, sort of challenge other players which are online. So i need internet connection anyway to show the user his current posisition in the ranking.. Is it still not adviced to do fetch it online if you know this?

Comment: if users can be added dynamically through game then its better to fetch online as it may change frequently.But once a user has logged into the game then you can store his whole info.No need to fetch it back

Comment: Still difficult in my eyes since other players have to be aware of the player its points. But I do agree that I can keep the info such as his points and status etc. in shared pref. If he wants to see the rankings, then I can connect to the internet...

Comment: well yes its better and as far as the awareness of others are concerened tou vcan maintain an online list for the same that shows name and points.keep the points dynamic rather than storing in shared preference,that may help :)